# Listview in alertDialog, positioning listview where I want it is where I'm stuck

Tags: java, android, xml, android-fragments

I have an alertDialog that is read by multiple fragments or activities, on one instance the alert dialog is going to show a listView with 2 editText options plus the standard positive and negative button presses, I want to position the listView after the editTexts and I'm stuck.

Everything displays properly but positioning is where I'm stuck.

Dialog class

```
public class addTaskDialog extends DialogFragment {

String mString;
taskDialogListener listener;
ArrayList<String> tradeTitles;

/*
 * Class interface from jobRoomDetails, interfaces are called from the parent activity class
 */
public interface taskDialogListener {
    void onDialogPositiveClick(DialogFragment dialog);
    void onDialogNegativeClick(DialogFragment dialog);
    void onDialogListSelect();
}

@Override
public void onAttach(@NonNull Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    try{
        listener = (taskDialogListener) context;
    } catch(ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException(getActivity().toString() + "must implement taskDialogListener");
    }
}

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    mString = getArguments().getString("title");
    tradeTitles = getArguments().getStringArrayList("tradeTitleArray");
    builder.setTitle(mString);


    //Inflate the layout dialog_add_task.xml
    LayoutInflater inflater = requireActivity().getLayoutInflater();

    //Pattern matcher for literal strings from different addTaskDialog calls
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("Add new task +");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(mString);
    Pattern q = Pattern.compile("Add Task +");
    Matcher n = q.matcher(mString);

    /*
     *Test for new task and add trade names, this means that the calling window is jobRoomDetails and this is a new task
     * and it will be assigned to a trade upon creation
     */
    if(m.find()){
        Log.d("Line: 56","Test for trade name" + tradeTitles.toString());
        final ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getContext(), android.R.layout.select_dialog_singlechoice, tradeTitles);
        //ListView list = (ListView) alert.findViewById(R.id.tradeItems);
        builder.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_add_task, null))
                .setPositiveButton(R.string.confirm, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                        //Save the new task to task hashmap
                        listener.onDialogPositiveClick(addTaskDialog.this);
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                        //Cancel operation and return
                        listener.onDialogNegativeClick(addTaskDialog.this);
                    }
                })
        .setAdapter(arrayAdapter, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
            }
        });

    } else if (n.find()){
        builder.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_add_task, null))
                .setPositiveButton(R.string.confirm, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                        //Save the new task to task hashmap
                        listener.onDialogPositiveClick(addTaskDialog.this);
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                        //Cancel operation and return
                        listener.onDialogNegativeClick(addTaskDialog.this);
                    }
                });

    } else {
        builder.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_add_task, null))
                .setPositiveButton(R.string.confirm, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                        //Save the new task to task hashmap
                        listener.onDialogPositiveClick(addTaskDialog.this);
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                        //Cancel operation and return
                        listener.onDialogNegativeClick(addTaskDialog.this);
                    }
                });

    }


    return builder.create();
}
}
```

dialog.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:orientation="vertical">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">
<TextView
    style="@style/textBox"
    android:layout_margin="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:text="@string/add_task_ex"/>
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/taskNameEditText"
    style="@style/editTextBox"
    android:hint="@string/add_task_name"
    android:inputType="text"/>
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/taskCost"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="0"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal"/>
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/tradeListItems"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/tradeItems"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
</androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>
```

At one point I tried to add it via a listView but to no success, I think the return type on the onCreateDialog might be hindering things but I'm not sure, I think the return type is necessary because I'm bringing through arguments but I could be wrong. As always help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer is create your own Alert dialog, you can simply make a fragment that looks and acts similar to an alert dialog but with far more functionality.